# Understand PDO fetch and fetchAll iteration with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, fetch

With this:

```
private function jsonArray($object)
{
  $json = array();

  if(isset($object) && !empty($object))
  {
    foreach($object as $obj)
    {
      ...
    }
  }

  return $json;

}
```

We iterate over an object with success. We use PDO::fetch[FETCH_OBJ] and it works.

What if, we want to iterate over an **array of objects** like the one returned by a fetchAll with the FETCH_OBJ attribute? Should the syntax be the same?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be as simple as having yet another foreach loop to iterate the array and then ("inside" that loop) do the same thing as before.

```
foreach($objects as $obj) {
  foreach($obj as $property) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried before, but no luck. Your answer still is valid. But the issue may rely on something else. :) Need to remake this question.

Comment: hm... this same issue, after some dump findings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736455/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-fetch-works-fetchall-doesnt