# jquery autocomplete plugin - fetch works - fetchAll doesn't

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autocomplete, iteration

If I have something like this from the server side, from a fetch:

```
array(1) { [0]=>  array(1) { ["nome"]=>  string(7) "aaaa.br" } } [{"nome":"aaaa.br"}]
```

The json of the above is:

```
[{"nome":"aaaa.br"}]
```

This Works:

```
parse: function(data) {
 return $.map(eval('('+data+')'), function(result) {
   return {
    data: result,
    value: result.nome,
    result: result.nome
   }
  });
}
```

The result is parsed successfully.

If, instead of fetch, I change to fetchAll, the dump gets like this (here only the first index as example):

```
array(65) { [0]=>  array(1) { ["nome"]=>  object(stdClass)#7 (1) { ["nomeDominio"]=>  string(7) "aaaa.br" } }
```

The json conversion of the above:

```
string(2632) "[{"nome":{"nomeDominio":"aaaa.br"}}
```

Here, the result is not successfully parsed.

So I believe something needs to be changed on the js side. 
But I'm absolutely clueless.

UPDATE: 
The nomeDominio is from the fetchObj PDO method, and corresponds to the column name on the database. It's a natural behaviour for fetch with PDO when FETCH::OBJ option is used.

The php part of this js is:

```
$keyword = addslashes($_GET["q"]);

$comandos = new ComandoController();

$arr = $comandos->recebeNomeDominios($keyword);

if(is_array($arr))
{
    echo json_encode($arr);

}


public function recebeNomeDominios($keyword)
{
   $DominioDao = new DominioDao();

   $objecto = $DominioDao->recebeNomeDominios($keyword);

   return $this->jsonArray($objecto);

}

private function jsonArray($objecto)
{
  $json = array();
  if(isset($objecto) && !empty($objecto))
  {
    foreach($objecto as $obj)
    {
      $json[] = array('nome' => $obj);

    }
  }
   return $json;
}
```

Finally:

```
public function recebeNomeDominios($keyword)
{
  try
  {
     $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT d.nomeDominio FROM dominio d WHERE d.nomeDominio LIKE '%".$keyword."%'");
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return $resultado;
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
  echo "Erro: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
}
```

Any advice?
MEM

Comment: Is this in conjuction with PHP's `PDO` extension...?

Comment: side-note. Why do you have to parse/eval the data "manually"? You can set the dataType to 'json' in your options object for the request and jquery handles the string->javascript conversion.

Comment: The two php arrays are already structurally different. Where does this `nomeDominio` thingy in the fetchAll version come from? You might want to show us the php code...

Comment: @Martin Bean: Yes it is.

Comment: @VolkerK - first comment - I would love to use that option if it works... for know however, and after weeks, I got this one to work with fetch and I just thought it would be easier to keep on this way... But I'm open to change it, if you can guide me on about how to do it. :s

Comment: @VolkerK - second comment - I will update my question to add the php part

Comment: You've added the code for building the query, sending it to the server and returning the result "resource"/object. But where's the code that actually retrieves the data and transforms it to json - for both the fetch() and the fetchAll() version?

Comment: @VolkerK - it's the first lines of code that appear after my update: 
if(is_array($arr))
{
    echo json_encode($arr);

} - there, I do encode the array and I echo it back to the browser for js consumption.

Comment: I don't think that the code and the output correspond. It looks more like you've used your jsonArray() method together with your fechAll version of recebeNomeDominios().

Comment: The difference between PDO's `fetch` and `fetchAll` methods is that, `fetch` will return the result set, whereas `fetchAll` will return an numerical array of result sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$comandos = new ComandoController();
$arr = $comandos->recebeNomeDominios($keyword);
echo json_encode($arr);


class ComandoController {
  public function recebeNomeDominios($keyword)
  {
    $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare('
      SELECT
        d.nomeDominio as nome
      FROM
        dominio
      WHERE nomeDominio LIKE :keyword
    ');
    $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyparam);
    $keyparam = '%'.str_replace('%', '\\%', $keyword) . '%';
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
...
```

Comment: I cannot wait to give it a try. Thanks a lot. Why fetch_assoc and not fetch_obj ?

Comment: "Why fetch_assoc" - No particular reason, just habit. Should work with FETCH_OBJ as well.

Comment: Well... I just found out that, on jsonArray, if we change from $json[] = array('nome' => $obj); to, $json[] = array('nome' => $obj->nomeDominio); it works perfectly. If you add this on your answer... I can mark it. :) It was so simple. Just adding a ->nomeDominio... oh well... I will use your code however, because you have help me solve another issue, the fact that I was unable to use bindParam with LIKE keywords. ;) I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you return one array (fetch) then you need to collect data from it like this

```
var name = data.name;
var age = data.age;
var gender = data.gender;
// Do something with values here
```

If you are using fetchAll, this will presumably return an array of arrays (a multidimensional array) which you will need to iterate over. From looking at `$.map` it looks like your using jQuery. Iterate over the multidimensional array like this

```
jQuery.each(data, function() {
    name = this.name;
    age = this.age;
    gender = this.gender;
    // Do something with values here
});
```

Comment: That will help... I'm sure... I've updated my question do you mind to take a look?